# @test no me funciona - PHPUnit - Laravel

Tags: laravel, phpunit

Estoy tratando de hacer algunas pruebas con phpunit desde laravel pero cuando escribo en el codigo de esta manera el `@test` se mantiene comentado como se ve en la imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por lo que me veo en la obligación de escribir test como palabra que inicia en todos los métodos que creo.

¿Cómo puedo solucionar esto? Deseo escribí `@test` en el comentario y poder correr las pruebas sin necesidad de escribirlo en el método.

Comment: La anotación está correcta, debería funcionar colocando cualquier otro nombre al método , ya no está obligado a escribir test al inicio.

Comment: Pero no funciona al enviar el comando no me reconoce el @test y tengo que colocarlo en el metodo.